# Get input scroll position in IE/Edge Javascript (JSFiddle included)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, input, microsoft-edge, scroll-position

Scenario:
When a user is typing in an input field and the text becomes longer than the field width, the text scrolls as the user types.
I was relying on scrollLeft to get the scroll position on an input field, and I only recently realized that this same code wasn't working in IE or Edge (It IS working in Chrome, Firefox and Safari).

Looking into it, element.scrollLeft is compatible with IE/Edge, but for whatever reason it only returns 0 in these browsers.  I saw another question on stackoverflow similar to mine, but there didn't seem to be a workaround.

How would someone go about getting the scroll position of an input field in IE/Edge?

Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/kellyag/bwac46yz/8/

```
function inputScrollPosition () {
  let input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  let scrollPosition = input.scrollLeft;

  console.log(scrollPosition)
};
```

Comment: By now, `input.scrollLeft` seems to be working in Edge

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround based on the discussion here: https://github.com/garysieling/jquery-highlighttextarea/issues/35

The workaround is to use a textarea instead (and style it like an input).
element.scrollLeft will work when the element is a textarea.

```
<textarea id="myInput" cols="50" rows="1" style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;"></textarea>
```

This version still needs some additional css styling, but the code is working:
https://jsfiddle.net/kellyag/ywzus94m/2/